# Hook menu alter - Restrict access to edit block - wrong page is shown

Tags: 7, hooks

I want to restrict the editing of a block to users whom have X or Y permissions.

I have tried `access arguments` and `access callback`.

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['admin/structure/block/manage/block/72/configure']['access arguments'] = ['X']; // ['X','Y'] uses AND not OR :(
}
```

I've attempted to add the 'Or' logic via a access callback function instead.

```
function _banner_block_access() {
    return user_access('X') || user_access('Y');
}

/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['admin/structure/block/manage/block/72/configure']['access callback'] = '_banner_block_access';
}
```

**The problem**

When the user has the correct permissions, they should see the block edit admin form.

What actually happens is the path `/admin/structure/block/manage/block/72/configure` shows the block index listing (`/admin/structure/block`) instead.

When the user doesn't have the right permission, a non authorised error is correctly displayed.

When the function returns `false` the view is correct and displays a not authorised message.

Is this a Drupal bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the Drupal core modules defines a route for admin/structure/block/manage/block/72/configure.

The block module has a route for admin/structure/block/manage/%/%/configure, but since that is a default tab, it inherits its access permissions from its parent route, admin/structure/block/manage/%/%.

The correct code to alter that route would be similar to the following one.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (isset($items['admin/structure/block/manage/%/%'])) {
    $items['admin/structure/block/manage/%/%']['access callback'] = '_banner_block_access';
    $items['admin/structure/block/manage/%/%']['access arguments'] = array(4, 5);
  }
}

function _banner_block_access($module, $block) {
  if ($module == 'block' && $block == 72) {
    return user_access('X') || user_access('Y');
  }

  // Use the default access for the other blocks.
  return user_access('administer blocks');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes perfect sense; however, I did still need to add /configure onto the end of /%/% for it to work.